# 2008 Acer laptop boot problems

Tags: boot, laptop, battery

5 days ago i made a post asking what charger adaptor would suit the ACER ASPIRE 6920G as i got one for 20EUR.

today an ORIGINAL laptop AC adapter arrived but it seem that the charger was not the issue.

The issue.

Number 1(BATTERY OUT PLUG IN )When you plug in the charger together with the battery (battery is uncharged hasn't been charged for maybe 10 years) and press the start button, the lights of the laptop turn on and the laptop seems to start but no its just fooling you ! it doesn't make the CD drive sound which means that it has made steps forward to boot, and the screen stays black after 2-6 seconds the laptop just shuts off and either tries to restart it self or it quits and gives up. The same also happens with the plug in.

Number 2(BATTERY IN PLUG OUT)Now things are different with the battery in, if you leave the laptop connected to the plug with the battery in for about 10-15 minutes the battery charge indicator located under the finger track pad switches from orange to green meaning the battery is charged, if you now disconnect the plug and press the power button the laptop will boot to the LINUX installation screen but turn off at some point by it self and wont turn on again.

Weird things: If you do No2 and at any point while its working connect the charger it instantly shuts down.

I want to mention that its SATA 2.5 HDD died and i will be booting it off a USB disk i have 2 plugged one with linux the other partitioned to install linux.

According to some googeling i made, people state it might be the static build up i tried, nothing of those "HOLD THE POWER BUTTON FOR A MINUTE" works, something weirder is going on.
The CPU and GPU are also not going hot as the fans barely spin and without the heatsink they dont get any close to over heating (i mean it we are talking about room temps). It also wont start just with the charger and without the battery.

I wonder if its the BIOS and im considering opening it up again to reset it but its a hassle so i want to ask on here first. Any answer appreciated but if you are here to tell me google it then no that doesn't count as an answer as i already tried that.

Comment: The battery is dead, no doubt about it. There may also be another problem with the power supply section on the motherboard. It's time to retire that laptop - the cost of repair will be a multiple of laptop's value.

Comment: well i posted on here to get solutions and not give up on it, its a great laptop and would do great just as a kali attack testing laptop, i would even go to the route of DIY as the laptop is so old that what do i have to lose. so if you got any recommendations rather telling me to give up on it i would appreciate them

Comment: Does it work after being plugged-in for some time?

Comment: yes but for shortly only lets say 5 minutes, currently i opened it up to check it with my current test tool it gets about 6V at the points it should,  when i plug in the power supply cable (the one that runs from the port to the MOBO) i see a spark, so i suspect there is a shortcircuit happening ONLY with the power cable in, so i suspect something is shorting it you can also hear buzzing (a zapping buzzing coming from the port which im sure you are not supposed to hear)

Comment: Get a good aftermarket battery from Dr Battery (Amazon)